# Cannot copy file content from one GPIO file to another file in C++?

Tags: c++, beagleboneblack, gpio, beagleboard

I have an issue copying the content from one GPIO file on a black beaglebone board to another. The code compiles correctly and the content that is copied from the input GPIO file (gpio15) is correct as it displays the output correctly to the terminal before attempting to write the output to the other GPIO file (gpio20). When it attempts to write to the output GPIO file ,however, the file remains unchanged. Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

```
    fstream fileread1; 
    string output1;

    fileread1.open("/sys.../gpiochip0/gpio/gpio15/value");

    if(fileread1.is_open()) {
        fileread1 >> output1;
        cout << output1 << " input success" << endl;
    }

    fileread1.close();

    fstream filewrite1;
    filewrite1.open("/sys/...gpiochip0/gpio/gpio20/value");

    if(filewrite1.is_open()) {
    filewrite1 << output1 << endl;
    cout << output1 << " output success" << endl;
    }

    filewrite1.close();
```

Comment: Is gpio20 configured as an output?

Comment: It was configured as an input. Thank you so much !